# Updating object set using removeAll in Spring with JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Proposal object that has a Set of Votes. A user has an amount of votes (let say 100 to be allocated with different proposal). A Proposal has an atribute type that allows the user to vote for it. When in Study the proposal can be modified, but not voted. When Approved, it can be voted, but when that attributes changes to Development and all the votes have to be cleared from the database and a user that has used his 100 votes for an approved proposal can get them back and vote for another.

I can create a proposal, my controllers can add a votes to the proposal fine and they appear at the database. The problem comes when I change the atribute type to Development. At that point, I can get the proposal from DB, send it to the proposal.deleteVote() method, removeAll the votes, get the proposal back with (null) votes, but when I save the proposal at the database it is not updated. The votes records that were deleted from the set are still there.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="proposal")
public class Proposal {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="functionality")
private String functionality;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="siteuserid")
private SiteUser siteUser;

@ManyToOne              
@JoinColumn(name = "statusupdateid")
private StatusUpdate statusUpdate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="proposal", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Vote> votes;

@Column(name="releasedate")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd")
private Date release;

@Column(name="proposal_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ProposalType proposalType;

@Transient
private int proposalVotes;

public Proposal() {
}

// CONSTRUCTORS GETTER AND SETTERS

public Set<Vote> getVotes() {
    return votes;
}

public void setVotes(Set<Vote> votes) {
    this.votes = votes;
}

public void addVote(Vote vote){
    votes.add(vote);
}

public Proposal deleteVote(Proposal proposal){

    HashSet <Vote> thevotes = new HashSet<Vote>();

    thevotes.removeAll(proposal.getVotes());

    return proposal;    
}

public int getProposalVotes() {
    return proposalVotes;
}

public void setProposalVotes(int proposalVotes) {
    this.proposalVotes = proposalVotes;
}
```

Here is the console log of the objects:
 BEFORE REMOVING VOTES: [id=1, ..., votes=[Vote [id=35, numberOfPoints=3], Vote [id=34, numberOfPoints=2]], rel...
 AFTER REMOVING VOTES: [id=1, ..., votes=null, rel...

And here is the Controllers method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editproposal", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editProposal(ModelAndView modelAndView, @Valid Proposal proposal, BindingResult result) {

    modelAndView.setViewName("app.editproposal");       
    SiteUser user = getUser();  
    if(!result.hasErrors()) {
        proposal.setSiteUser(user);
        if(proposal.getProposalType().equals(ProposalType.ESTUDIO)){
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/myproposals");

        } else if (proposal.getProposalType().equals(ProposalType.APROBADO)){
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/myproposals");
        } else if 
            (proposal.getProposalType().equals(ProposalType.DESARROLLO)){  
         proposal.deleteVote(proposalService.findOneById(proposal.getId()));
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/myproposals");

        } else if (proposal.getProposalType().equals(ProposalType.PRODUCCION)){
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/myproposals");
        }
        proposalService.createProposal(proposal);
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/myproposals");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

The proposalService is here. The proposal gets to it without the votes (null)
 but it is not updated at the database (no error is giving). I have no idea why it does that.

```
    public void createProposal(Proposal proposal){
    System.out.println("!!!! ProposalService + createProposal .... " +proposal);
    proposalDao.save(proposal);
}
```

The vote entity is here:

```
package com.caveofprogramming.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="votes")
public class Vote {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="siteuserid")
private SiteUser siteUser;

@ManyToOne                     
private Proposal proposal;

@Column(name="points")
private int numberOfPoints;

public Vote() {
}

public Vote(Long id, SiteUser siteUser, Proposal proposal, int numberOfPoints) {
    this.id = id;
    this.siteUser = siteUser;
    this.proposal = proposal;
    this.numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public SiteUser getSiteUser() {
    return siteUser;
}

public void setSiteUser(SiteUser siteUser) {
    this.siteUser = siteUser;
}

public Proposal getProposal() {
    return proposal;
}

public void setProposal(Proposal proposal) {
    this.proposal = proposal;
}

public int getNumberOfPoints() {
    return numberOfPoints;
}

public void setNumberOfPoints(int numberOfPoints) {
    this.numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Vote [id=" + id + ", numberOfPoints=" + numberOfPoints + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: can you share your full controller method and the vote Entity?

Comment: @Amer Qarabsa done, but the other edit has been rejected. Can you see it now?

Comment: Look at your public deleteVote(Proposal proposal) method. It doesn't make any sense. It creates a new empty HashSet, then removes things from this empty HashSet. Not to mention that it's a method of Proposal, that takes another Proposal as argument, and returns that Proposal... that the caller already knows, since it just apssed it as argument. And even if it did remove votes from the proposal's votes, it doesn't modify the owner side of the association (i.e. set the vote's proposal to null), so JPA wouldn't care.